# Debugging Node.js applications from inside Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose

When debugging a Node.js application, I expect the command `node index.js --inspect=5858` to make my index.js file debuggable on the port 5858.

When I run the application outside of Docker, on my host computer, I'm able to debug the application in Chrome Dev Tools. I did the same inside of Docker and Chrome Dev Tools is unable to access the debugger on port 5858.

As you can see, port 5858 is exposed to the host computer for debugging:

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    build: .
    command: node index.js --inspect=5858
    volumes:
     - .:/app
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
     - "5858:5858"
    environment:
     - NODE_ENV = "development"
```

I've specified `localhost:5858` and `127.0.0.1:5858` network endpoints in Chrome Dev Tools, though still Dev Tools does not connect to it automatically as it suggests.

This seems to be an issue with my Docker setup though as you can see, I have exposed the port to the host computer. What could be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to get into your container's shell and see if localhost:5858 *is* up and running? If not, try `docker exec -it container_id sh`

Comment: @serey I checked that it's running in Docker with `netstat -tulpn` and port 5858 is running with program name `45/node` so it is running

Comment: @PavSidhu Did you exported the port 5858 at Dockerfile?

Comment: @CauêAlves I just tried that and had no luck. In Kitematic, it shows that the ports 5858 and 8000, so it appears that they are being exposed properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when you are running it inside the container it is listening only to localhost by default. So you have two options

**Use host network**

Add `network_mode: host` to your service and remove the port mappings. Not an ideal thing to do

**Make sure nodejs listens to every IP**

Change

`command: node index.js --inspect=5858`

to

`command: node --inspect=0.0.0.0:5858 index.js`